# Linear regression with a categorical variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a linear model with one dependent variable y = b0 + b1 * x and need to add a categorical feature to it. The problem is that training for each category should result in its own curve (b0, b1 pair). Each category is a different process. I'm tempted to use the simplest way: create a dict and train a separate model for each process.

Does this problem fall into regular linear regression? Can I use tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor?

I've read about [TF's linear model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/wide/) and [categorical variables in statistics](http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/multibook/mlt08m.html) and others, but seems its don't address the issue (or I cannot apply it correctly).

Comment: Sounds like logistic regression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

Comment: Thanks for you comment. But my dependent variable is continuous, not categorical. Does it still fall into logistic regression?